# About app scoped user id in facebook api 2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

As you may know there's an `app scoped user Id` facebook api 2.0 onwards, it's backward compatible for people who have logged into the app before, they will still have the original id.

But I want to know if a user who logged into the app when it was still using API 1.0, then de-authorized the app, and logged in again when the app has upgraded to 2.0, will this user have the original Id or a new app scoped used id?

Answer (score 0):

If a user de-authorized you app and then authorized it again you'll get the **`app scode id`** instead of original `id`. The fresh install (authorization) has nothing to do what user had done previously with that app!